# Split text with tab on vba

Tags: vba, split, tabs

I have read a text file which has more than 100 columns, separated by tab. This code read one line into a string for every rows. How can I import all lines into different columns (I have to do this procedure for about 100 files).

```
Sub reader()

Dim filePath As String
Dim text As String
Dim x As Integer
filePath = "C:\Users\Squirrel\Desktop\CodePack\account_inf.txt"

Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading, False)

Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    text = txtStream.ReadLine
    x = x + 1
    Cells(x, 1).Value = Left(text, 1)
Loop
txtStream.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, you have to built a program splitting the string by tab and writing the values to the other columns:

```
Cells(1, 1) = "ah" & vbTab & "kakva si!" & vbTab & _
                "antilopa" & vbTab & "Gazella"
```

Writes `ah kakva si! antilopa Gazella` in Range("A1") and then it splits it to the other columns like this:

[image]

```
Sub TestMe()

    Cells(1, 1) = "ah" & vbTab & "kakva si!" & vbTab & _
                    "antilopa" & vbTab & "Gazella"

    Dim wholeString As Variant
    wholeString = Split(Cells(1, 1), vbTab)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(wholeString) To UBound(wholeString)
        Cells(1, i + 1) = wholeString(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could open your tab-delimited file with one command:

```
Workbooks.OpenText "C:\yourPath\yourTabSeparatedFile.txt", _
    xlMSDOS, , xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, False, True, False, False, False
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Workbooks.OpenText**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel)
- Wikipedia : [**Tab-separated values**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values)

Answer (score 0):

Importing text files, splitted by tab is probably best if you use `QueryTables.Add` and set the property `TextFileTabDelimiter = True`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\Squirrel\Desktop\CodePack\account_inf.txt", Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "SomeName"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```